# How do I make my sourdough crust thinner?

Tags: sourdough, crust

I have been playing around with my sourdough recipes, and I can't figure out how to make my crust thinner.

Only things I do out of the ordinary are when baking I have a pot of hot water in the oven to increase humidity, I spray my dough with warm water in the last hour of rising. I also add citric acid for more tang.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use less sourdough, and stop adding humidity to the oven?

Both sourdough cultures and increasing oven humidity are ways bakers use to *increase* the crust thickness and crunch.  If you want thin-crusted, soft bread, then you're doing all the wrong things.